# Max size for a screenshot (memory buffer)

Tags: iphone, crash, calayer, retina-display

the entire block of code consists of the following:

```
CGSize layerSize = [webview sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layerSize, NO, 2.0f);
} 
else {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layerSize);
}

[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but after testing, this line is the one causing the problem:
    [webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

seems like a memory crash , is there a max size (width x height) based on device (ipod , iphone, ipad) where this function crashes - seems to crash for very long pages on retina display ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that memory issuse is causing your problem. You should take screenshot with `void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size,BOOL opaque,CGFloat scale);`. Last parameter set to 0.0 will take care of retina/non-retina issue.

"The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen." From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webview.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**EDIT:** you say your app is still crashing.

Is it possible that you forgot to add `QuartzCore framework`.

You also have to import `QuartzCore header`:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

from [Technical Q&A QA1703 (Screen Capture in UIKit Applications)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193)

Comment: i tried your suggestion  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions (webview.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);but still crashes.    Memory Monitor in Instruments flags it as memory error and closes the app - so this is definitely a memory issue.

Comment: @akishnani: see my edited answer: could that be a reason? also take a look at linked Q&A

Comment: no dice - still crashing,  i had included <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> header and framework.

Comment: @akishnani: and if you comment out `UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` it doesn't crash? I'm still almost sure that this shouldn't be a memory issue. But am out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: it is crashing on this line : [webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; It is 100% a memory issue since the Profiling Memory Monitor : Flags it as Memory Error

Answer (score 0):

Hi akishnani I had the same issue, After having suffered and googled everything I just found out that I was overriding - `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method, and it was creating the problem, It may fix the problem, if not solved yet.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty old thread, but what is found is to limit the height of the screenshot.

**I specified an upper limit (4000 CGFloat) and if the content I have to take a screenshot of exceeds that, I crop the screenshot at upper limit.**

This has helped me reduce the recurrence of the memory error.